# How can i resolve a TypeError in the Integration of JavaScript and Prisma?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror, prisma

Hey Im building a apication with react.js and prisma, the aplication runs properly however for some reason I'm getting a `TypeError: createProject is not a function` these are the pages.

projectService.js:

```
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const { v4: uuid } = require('uuid')
require('dotenv').config()


const prisma = new PrismaClient()
class Project {
    async Create(title, description, projectType, coleaderId, ownerId) {

        try {
            const project = await prisma.project.create({
                data: {
                    id: uuid(),
                    title: title,
                    description: description,
                    projectType: projectType,
                    coleaderId: coleaderId,
                    ownerId: ownerId
                }
            })

            return project
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error('Error creating project')
        }
    }


    async update(id, data) {
        //Verify if project exists
        const project = await prisma.project.findUnique({
            where: {
                id: id
            }
        })

        if (!project) {
            throw new Error('Project not found')
        }

        if(!data) {
            throw new Error('No data to update')
        }

        try {
            const project = await prisma.project.update({
                where: {
                    id: id
                },
                data,
            })

            return project
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error('Error updating project')
        }
    }

    async delete(id) {
        //Verify if project exists
        const project = await prisma.project.findUnique({
            where: {
                id: id
            }
        })

        if (!project) {
            throw new Error('Project not found')
        }

        try {
            const project = await prisma.project.delete({
                where: {
                    id: id
                }
            })

            return "Project deleted with success"
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error('Error deleting project')
        }
    }

    async getProject(id) {
        //Verify if project exists
        const project = await prisma.project.findUnique({
            where: {
                id: id
            }
        })

        if (!project) {
            throw new Error('Project not found')
        }

        return project
    }
}

module.exports = {
    Project,
}
```

projectController.js

```
const projectService = require('../services/projectService')

async function createProject(req, res) {
  const project = await projectService.createProject(req.body)
  res.json(project)
}
const GetProjectbyID = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params

  //Valida se algum paremetro é inválido
  const errors = validationResult(req)

  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({
          error: errors.errors[0].msg,
      })
  }

  //Chamada para o service
  try {
      //Tratamento das respostas do método da classe
      const result = await User.GetProject(id)
      res.send(result)
  } catch (err) {
      const date = new Date()
      if (err.message) {
          console.log(`[${date.getDate()}-${date.getUTCMonth()+1}-${date.getFullYear()} | ${date.getHours()-3}:${date.getMinutes()}]`,err.message)
      }
      res.status(500).send(err.message)
  }
}
module.exports = {
  createProject,
  GetProjectbyID,
}
```

projectRoutes.js

```
// projectRoutes.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { createProjectMiddleware } = require('../middlewares/projectMiddleware');

console.log('createProjectMiddleware');

router.post('/projects', createProjectMiddleware, (req, res) => {
  res.json(res.locals.project);
});

module.exports = router;

console.log('routers')
```

projectMiddleware.js

```
const { createProject } = require('../services/projectService');
console.log('createProject');

async function createProjectMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const project = await createProject(req.body);
    res.locals.project = project;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
}

module.exports = {
  createProjectMiddleware,
};
console.log('createProjectMiddleware')
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
require('express-async-errors')
require('dotenv').config()
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')

Object.keys(require.cache).forEach(function(key) {
    delete require.cache[key];
  });
  

const app = express()
app.use(cors())

app.use(express.json()) //Irá suportar JSON
app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        // Irá suportar urlenconded
        extended: true,
    })
)

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Pong!')
})

// Rotas
const userRouter = require('./routes/user')
app.use('/v1/user', userRouter)

const projectRouter = require('./routes/projectRoutes')
app.use('/v1/project', projectRouter)

const contentRouter = require('./routes/contentRoutes')
app.use('/v1/content', contentRouter)

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.status(404).send({ error: 'Not found', status: 404, url: req.url })
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Servidor rodando na porta http://localhost:${PORT}`)
})
```

I've ran `node app.js` and the aplication is running properly, however whenever i try to test the create project endpoint i get a type error

```
PS C:\Users\stefa\OneDrive\Documentos\Faculdade\Modulo 3 - B\Repositorio Grupo\Grupo-4\app\backend> node app.js
createProject
createProjectMiddleware
createProjectMiddleware
routers
Servidor rodando na porta http://localhost:3001
TypeError: createProject is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

You have exported the class `Project` in the file `projectService.js` which has a method named `create()` is defined, but while in the `projectController.js` file you imported the class and called `createProject()` instead of `create()`

just change the function name in `projectController.js` as below

```js
async function createProject(req, res) {
  const project = await projectService.create(req.body)
  res.json(project)
}
```